# Javascript/Jquery fetching quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, yahoo-api

I am new to java-scripting and I shouldn't be doing this in first place. But I was trying out the following
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>p { color:red; }</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
    }
);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Not loaded yet.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The above script works as expected. But I tried to replace the script with the following, expecting magic to happen(stock quote pulled in to the page). But I get a "Not loaded yet" message. Could someone point out what could be going wrong(or too many things done wrong) ?

[stock quotes with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150040/stock-quotes-with-javascript)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var symbol='goog';
            var callback = function(data) {
                    var price=data.query.results.span[0].content;
                    alert('Stock Price: ' + price);
                };

            var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
            // this is the lovely YQL query (html encoded) which lets us get the stock price:
            // select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=goog" and xpath='//span[@id="yfs_l10_goog"]'
            var data = "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3D" + symbol + "%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fspan%5B%40id%3D%22yfs_l10_" + symbol + "%22%5D'&format=json";
            $.getJSON(url, data, callback);
    });
</script>
```

this is how my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>p { color:red; }</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var symbol='goog';
            var callback = function(data) {
                    var price=data.query.results.span[0].content;
                    //alert('Stock Price: ' + price);
                    //$("p").price;
                    $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
                };

            var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
            // this is the lovely YQL query (html encoded) which lets us get the stock price:
            // select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=goog" and xpath='//span[@id="yfs_l10_goog"]'
            var data = "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3D" + symbol + "%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fspan%5B%40id%3D%22yfs_l10_" + symbol + "%22%5D'&format=json";
            $.getJSON(url, data, callback);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Not loaded yet.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the call being made? what's being returned? use Google Chrome dev tools or Firebug, and take a look at the Network tab when the page loads. You should see the call being made, take a look at the response to see what might be going on

Comment: The query works, but here is the result : {count: 0,created: "2013-06-14T17:36:55Z",lang: "en-US",results: null}, so the problem comes from your parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than:

```
 var data = "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3D" + symbol + "%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fspan%5B%40id%3D%22yfs_l10_" + symbol + "%22%5D'&format=json";
```

Do this: it's more maintainable:

```
var data = $.param({q:'select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=' + symbol + '" and xpath="//span[\'@id=yfs_l10_' + symbol + '\']"',format:'json'});
```

The response I got:

```
{"query":{"count":95,"created":"2013-06-14T17:57:32Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"span":[{"class":"yucs-notif-panel-title","content":"Notifications"},"Search",{"class":"title","content":"Breaking News"},{"class":"close","content":"×\n            "},{"class":"offscreen","content":"Close this window"},"HOME","INVESTING","NEWS","PERSONAL FINANCE","MY PORTFOLIOS","EXCLUSIVES","CNBC","\n                      \n                    ","\n                        \n                      ",{"input":{"id":"btnQuotes","type":"submit","value":"Get Quotes"}},{"id":"yfs_market_time","content":"Fri, Jun 14, 2013, 1:57PM EDT - U.S. Markets close in 2 hrs 3 mins"},{"id":"yfs_ad_"},{"a":{"href":"/q?s=%5EDJI","content":"Dow"}},{"id":"yfs_pp0_^dji","img":{"alt":"Down","border":"0","class":"neg_arrow","height":"14","src":"http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png","style":"margin-right:-2px;","width":"10"},"strong":{"class":" yfi-price-change-down","content":"0.77%"}},{"a":{"href":"/q?s=%5EIXIC","content":"Nasdaq"}},{"id":"yfs_pp0_^ixic","img":{"alt":"Down","border":"0","class":"neg_arrow","height":"14","src":"http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png","style":"margin-right:-2px;","width":"10"},"strong":{"class":" yfi-price-change-down","content":"0.69%"}},"Ticker Tape:",{"id":"tt_on","style":"display:inline;","content":"On"},{"id":"tt_off","style":"display:none;","content":"Off"},{"class":"rtq_exch","content":"\n                    NasdaqGS"},{"class":"rtq_dash","content":"-"},{"class":"time_rtq_ticker"},{"id":"yfs_l84_intc","content":"24.90"},{"class":"down_r time_rtq_content"},{"id":"yfs_c63_intc","img":{"alt":"Down","border":"0","class":"neg_arrow","height":"14","src":"http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png","style":"margin-right:-2px;","width":"10"},"content":"\n                     0.09"},{"id":"yfs_p43_intc","content":"(0.36%)"},{"class":"time_rtq"},{"id":"yfs_t53_intc"},{"id":"yfs_t53_intc","content":"1:57PM EDT"},{"class":"add-to-portfolio-button","a":{"class":"add-to-portfolio-icon","href":"http://edit.finance.yahoo.com/ec?.src=quote&.intl=us&.sym=INTC&.done=http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3DINTC"}},"Add to Portfolio",{"id":"yfs_b00_intc","content":"24.88"},{"id":"yfs_b60_intc","content":"3800"},{"id":"yfs_a00_intc","content":"24.89"},{"id":"yfs_a50_intc","content":"18800"},{"id":"earn_cal_div","a":{"onclick":"window.open('http://calendar.yahoo.com/?v=60&ST=20130717&TITLE=INTC Earnings announcement&VIEW=d&REM1=7d&REM2=1d', 'earnwin', 'toolbars=no,scrollbars=no')","img":{"alt":"INTC Earnings announcement","class":"earn_cal_icon","id":"earn_cal_img","src":"http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png","title":"INTC Earnings announcement"}}},"\n                        \n                      ",{"id":"yfs_g53_intc","content":"24.84"},"\n                        \n                      ",{"id":"yfs_h53_intc","content":"25.14"},"19.23","27.75",{"id":"yfs_v53_intc","content":"16,120,889"},{"class":"small","content":"(3m)"},{"id":"yfs_j10_intc","content":"123.78B"},{"class":"small","content":"(ttm)"},{"class":"small","content":"(ttm)"},{"a":[{"href":"/q?s=MSFT&reco=1","strong":"MSFT"},{"href":"/q?s=CSCO&reco=1","strong":"CSCO"},{"href":"/q?s=AMD&reco=1","strong":"AMD"},{"href":"/q?s=QCOM&reco=1","strong":"QCOM"},{"href":"/q?s=PFE&reco=1","strong":"PFE"},{"href":"/q?s=DELL&reco=1","strong":"DELL"}]},{"id":"trdnow_success"},{"class":"broker-head","content":"Featured Brokers"},{"class":"resetlink","a":{"href":"#","id":"reset_brkr","content":"Reset"}},{"class":"err_msg","id":"trdnow_err"},"(Fri 1:28PM EDT)","(Fri 1:04PM EDT)","(Fri 1:00PM EDT)","(Fri 10:25AM EDT)","(Fri 10:13AM EDT)","(Fri 10:08AM EDT)","(Fri 10:01AM EDT)","(Fri 9:30AM EDT)","(Fri 9:04AM EDT)","(Fri 6:16AM EDT)","(Fri 6:13AM EDT)","(Fri 5:10AM EDT)","(Thu, Jun 13)","(Thu, Jun 13)","(Thu, Jun 13)","(Tue, Jun 11)","(Tue, Jun 11)","(Mon, Jun 10)","(Jun 15)","(Jun 14)","(Jun 14)",{"id":"yfs_ad_"},{"id":"yfs_ad_"},{"id":"yfs_pp0_intc","img":{"alt":"Down","border":"0","class":"neg_arrow","height":"14","src":"http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png","style":"margin-right:-2px;","width":"10"},"strong":{"class":" yfi-price-change-down","content":"0.36%"}},{"id":"yfs_j10_intc","content":"123.78B"},{"id":"yfs_pp0_arm.l","img":{"alt":"Up","border":"0","class":"pos_arrow","height":"14","src":"http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png","style":"margin-right:-2px;","width":"10"},"strong":{"class":" yfi-price-change-up","content":"0.58%"}},{"id":"yfs_j10_arm.l","content":"12.04B"},{"id":"yfs_pp0_intc.mx","img":{"alt":"Up","border":"0","class":"pos_arrow","height":"14","src":"http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png","style":"margin-right:-2px;","width":"10"},"strong":{"class":" yfi-price-change-up","content":"0.39%"}},{"id":"yfs_j10_intc.mx","content":"1.57T"},{"id":"yfs_pp0_tsmn.mx","img":{"alt":"Down","border":"0","class":"neg_arrow","height":"14","src":"http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png","style":"margin-right:-2px;","width":"10"},"strong":{"class":" yfi-price-change-down","content":"4.13%"}},{"id":"yfs_j10_tsmn.mx","content":"1.20T"},{"id":"yfs_pp0_4335.hk","strong":{"class":" yfi-price-no-change","content":"0.00%"}},{"class":"label","content":"Sector"},{"class":"label","content":"Industry"},{"id":"yfs_ad_"},{"id":"yfs_ad_"},{"id":"yfs_params_vcr","style":"display:none","content":"{\"yrb_token\" : \"YFT_MARKET_WILL_CLOSE\", \"tt\" : \"1371232652\", \"s\" : \"intc\", \"k\" : \"a00,a50,b00,b20,b30,b60,c10,c60,c63,c64,c81,c82,c85,c86,g00,g53,h00,h53,j10,l10,l84,l85,l86,l90,o40,o50,p20,p40,p43,p44,t10,t50,t53,t54,v00,v53,z08,z09\", \"o\" : \"4335.hk,arm.l,intc.mx,tsmn.mx,^dji,^ixic,intc,^ixic,^gspc,^dji,^tnx,^vix,^rut,EURUSD=X\", \"j\" : \"c10,c63,j10,l10,l84,p20,p43,t10,t53,v00\", \"e\" : \"1\", \"version\" : \"1.0\", \"market\" : {\"NAME\" : \"U.S.\", \"ID\" : \"us_market\", \"TZ\" : \"EDT\", \"TZOFFSET\" : \"-14400\", \"open\" : \"\", \"close\" : \"\", \"flags\" : {}} , \"market_status_yrb\" : \"YFT_MARKET_WILL_CLOSE\" , \"portfolio\" : { \"fd\" : { \"txns\" : [ ]},\"dd\" : \"\",\"pc\" : \"\",\"pcs\" : \"\"}, \"SINGLE_QUOTE_PAGE\" : { \"symbol\" : \"INTC\",\"name\" : \"Intel Corporation\"}, \"STREAMER_SERVER\" : \"http://streamerapi.finance.yahoo.com\", \"DOC_DOMAIN\" : \"finance.yahoo.com\", \"localize\" : \"0\" , \"throttleInterval\" : \"1000\" , \"arrowAsChangeSign\" : \"true\" , \"up_arrow_icon\" : \"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/fi/03rd/up_g.gif\" , \"down_arrow_icon\" : \"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/fi/03rd/down_r.gif\" , \"up_color\" : \"green\" , \"down_color\" : \"red\" , \"pass_market_id\" : \"0\" , \"mu\" : \"1\" , \"lang\" : \"en-US\" , \"region\" : \"US\" , \"ticker_currency_sym\" : \"USD\" }"},{"id":"yfs_ad_"}]}}}
```

Comment: I found something called YQL Console and I played around with it along with your improved var data and new span =27 - Works now!

Comment: How do I pass more than one argument to callback function ? In my case I am trying to pass symbol along with data.

Comment: As your code looks right now, `symbol` is in the scope along with `callback`, so you should be able to access it within callback without passing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that there is something wrong with that huge query string you are building.

If you try to just go to that site in your browser with `goog` substituted in the right places:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3Dgoog%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fspan%5B%40id%3D%22yfs_l10_goog%22%5D'&format=json
```

You will see that the site fails to load. Make sure you can reach the site in your browser first, then make sure that matches up with your code.